# add apostrophes with regular expression in perl

Tags: perl, expression

I am searching directories with the command `ls -ld /path1/*.ext1 /path2/*.ext2, etc.`

Sometimes, the the names of files have special characters: `)`, `(`, etc.

Because of this, I want to add apostrophes to each search directories.

**For example:**

```
$filter="ls -ld /path1/*ext1 /path2/*ext2"; (1)

$filter=~ ...                             ; (2)
```

The result after applying the regular expression should be :

```
ls -ld '/path1/*ext1' '/path2/*ext2'   (with apostrophes)
```

What is the regular expression that should be placed in (2) ?

Comment: You should not be [parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) in the first place.  Depending on what you want to accomplish, look at `opendir` and/or `stat` and/or `File::Find`.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `ls`.  Use Perl's built-in globbing and the stat operator to get the information you need.  Note that if you wrap `'/path1/*ext1'` in single quotes (or double quotes), the shell is not going to expand the `*` for you; it will look for a file named specifically `/path1/*ext1` rather than all file names in `/path1` that end with `ext1`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick as you asked:

```
$filter =~ s!(\S+)!'$1'!g;
```

The better way to do this:

```
while (glob("/path1/*ext1 /path2/*ext2"){
  process_file($_);
}
```

Regards,